# google app engine go datastore check for entity existence using key

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

Given a stringId key for an entity, how do I check if there is a corresponding entity in datastore. I do not want to fetch the entity completely. I want to check if the entity exists or not.
Is there a performance impact if I fetch the complete entity to check its existence? Or is there a better way?

```
var Person struct {
   stringId string //string id which makes the key
   //many other properties.
}

//insert into datastore
_, err := datastore.Put(ctx, datastore.NewKey(ctx, entityKind, stringId, 0, nil), entity)
//retrieve the entity
datastore.Get(ctx, datastore.NewKey(ctx, entityKind, stringId, 0, nil), entity);
```

Instead of retrieving complete entity for a given stringId, is there a better way to check the entity exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To retrieve only key(s) add `KeysOnly()` to the end of your query, ie

```
q := datastore.NewQuery(entityKind).Filter(...).KeysOnly()
```

And yes, keys only query should be faster, quote from the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/queries):

> A keys-only query returns just the keys of the result entities instead of the entities themselves, at lower latency and cost than retrieving entire entities

BTW, to retrieve an entity by it's key, you can also use the special property `__key__`, ie

```
qKey := datastore.NewKey(ctx, entityKind, stringId, 0, nil)
q := datastore.NewQuery(entityKind).Filter("__key__ =", qKey)
```

Comment: Is there a way to check this for multiple keys in one call? datastore has GetMulti function to return multiple entities. But can we do that for Queries? For example, I have a list of keys (random strings) with me and want to know if there are corresponding entities in datastore for them. I did not find "in" operator for Query filter.

Comment: @sumanj you can't do that yet, you should use a loop to run the query

Comment: Apparently now there is a IN operator
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/queries#filters